# Issue in PlayFramework for external Jars

Tags: java, scala, paypal, playframework-2.0, dependencies

I downloaded PayPal API jars from grepcode and , and my java code is compiling successfully, but i want to access java code into my **playFramework controller**

```
object PayPalController extends Controller {

  def initialize = Action {

    val ack=PayPalDAO.initialize().getAck().toString() // returning  SetExpressCheckoutResponseType

  // I'm accessing here my JavaCallss models.PayPalDAO.java
    println(ack);

    Ok("")
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Play doesn't see your jar.

When you want to add unmanaged dependency you need to copy the jar to lib folder in the root of your play project and then reload the project (or just restart play).

```
your-project-root
- app
- conf
- lib <- you need to create this and copy the jar there
... whatever else
```

For details see http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTDependencies

Comment: i create a _lib_ folder insde project folder, but its not cleaning and not updating, and giving error...